# FZF broken displaying in emacs terminal

Tags: shell, eshell, ansi-term, term, multi-term

I'm struggling to run fzf in emacs but cannot figure out whats my problem. When I run fzf - and start typing - text gets mess up, similar to this:

[image]
I tried run fzf in term, eshell, ansi-term, multi-term modes, with and without --color=no option, its all the same. Does anyone knows what is my problem could be? Thx.

Comment: eshell doesn't support interactive programs, [see this](https://masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell). But I tried ansi-term calling fzf with keybindings (`CRTL-T`, `CTRL-R`, `ALT-C`) and it just works. It maybe related to your .emacs.d

Comment: @Choma what variable did you set to not use ESHELL and ansi-term instead?

Comment: @DarrylHebbes, I just did `M-x ansi-term`, it will ask you for a program to run, with /bin/bash as default